# Mount a network drive in linux using c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, mount

I want to mount a network drive on linux using c++. Using the command line of "mount" , I am able to mount any drive I want. But using C++, Only those drives are mounted successfully which are shared by the user.

This is my test code:

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string src = "//192.168.4.11/c$/Users";
  string dst = "/home/krahul/Desktop/test_mount";
  string fstype = "cifs";

  printf("src: %s\n", src.c_str());

  if( -1 == mount(src.c_str(), dst.c_str(), fstype.c_str(), MS_MGC_VAL | MS_SILENT , "username=uname,password=pswd") )
  {
      printf("mount failed with error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  else
      printf("mount success!\n");

  if( umount2(dst.c_str(), MNT_FORCE) < 0 )
  {
      printf("unmount failed with error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  else
      printf("unmount success!\n");


  return 0;
}
```

I want to mount the "C:/Users" drive of the machine. Using the Command line, It works but not by this code. I don't know why. The error printed by strerror() is "No such device or address". I am using Centos and Samba is configured for this machine. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: C is not C++, fix your question. Then, for the future, please indent your code consistently before posting and strip unnecessary parts. BTW: You can also check the sources for the mount program.

Comment: which command you use in shell to mount your network disk? I think maybe `string src = "//192.168.4.11/c$/Users";` have problem

Comment: I use the following shell command "mount  //192.168.4.11/c$/Users /mnt/test_mount -o username=uname,password=pswd", and this works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mount.cifs command parses and changes the options that are passed to the mount system call. Use the `-v` option to see what it uses for the system call.

```
$ mount -v -t cifs -o username=guest,password= //bubble/Music /tmp/xxx
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=127.0.1.1,unc=\\bubble\Music,user=guest,pass=********
```

i.e. it gets the IP address of the target system (replacing my `bubble` for `127.0.1.1` in the ip option), and passing in the full UNC with backslashes to the mount system call.

Rewriting your example with my mount options we have:

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string host = "127.0.1.1";
  string src = "\\\\bubble\\Music";
  string dst = "/tmp/xxx";
  string fstype = "cifs";

  string all_string = "unc=" + src + ",ip=" + host + ",username=guest,password=";

  printf("src: %s\n", src.c_str());

  if( -1 == mount(src.c_str(), dst.c_str(), fstype.c_str(), MS_MGC_VAL | MS_SILENT , all_string.c_str()))
  {
      printf("mount failed with error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  else
      printf("mount success!\n");

  if( umount2(dst.c_str(), MNT_FORCE) < 0 )
  {
      printf("unmount failed with error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  else
      printf("unmount success!\n");


  return 0;
}
```

This should help you when writing your tool to invoke `mount2`.